# Polymer - Full Screen Layout With Neon Animated Pages

Tags: css, layout, polymer

I have a Polymer app. I'm trying to make my app "full screen". However, one of the areas of the app uses animation. The use of [neon animated pages](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/neon-animation) is causing some challenges. Basically, I'm trying to create a layout that looks like this:

```
+----------------------------------------+
| My App                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
| +---------------------+  +-----------+ |
| | Content A           |  | Content C | |
| +---------------------+  | details   | |
|                          | go        | |
| +---------------------+  | here      | |
| | Content B           |  +-----------+ |
| | This area fills the |                |
| | rest of the height  |                |
| | and is scrollable   |                |
| |                     |                |
| |                     |                |
| |                     |                |
| +---------------------+                |
+----------------------------------------+
```

The use of the `neon-animated-pages` seems to throw the height off. That, and in addition the fact the components are nested is causing issues. I've created a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mbhU5TUS4YYMNwPxCLI0?p=preview). I believe the relevant code is in this section:

```
<dom-module id="app-view">  
    <template>
        <neon-animated-pages selected="[[selectedPageIndex]]" entry-animation="fade-in-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation" style="height:100%;">
          <view-1></view-1>
          <view-2></view-2>
        </neon-animated-pages>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "app-view",
                ready: function() {
                    this.selectedPageIndex = 0;
                }
        });
  </script> 
</dom-module>
```

It's like setting the `height` CSS property above is irrelevant or something. I'm not sure though. What am I doing wrong? How do I get a content area to fill the remaining part of the screen and make the overflow scroll within the world of Polymer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues in your *index.html* and *view-1.html* and let's go through each of them.

### index.html

Inside the `<body>...</body>` tag, the code can be simplified as this -

```
<body class="fullbleed layout vertical">
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <paper-header-panel class="flex">
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div class="spacer title">My App</div>        
      </paper-toolbar>

      <app-view class="fit"></app-view>
    </paper-header-panel>
  </template>

  <script>
    addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {});
  </script>
</body>
```

Note the `fullbleed layout vertical` on `<body>` and `flex` on `paper-header-panel`. Notice I applied a `fit` to the `app-view` so it fills up the whole page.

I also added this piece of *CSS* to set the `body`'s `padding` to `0`.

```
body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

This is because somehow the body has a default `padding` of `24px` and if I don't  do it the *scrollbar* will appear inside the *plunker*.

### view-1.html

See the updated code below.

```
<div class="fit horizontal layout">
    <div class="flex-9 vertical layout">
        <paper-material elevation="1" style="padding:0px;">
            Welcome
    </paper-material>

    <div style="height:24px;">&nbsp;</div>

    <paper-material elevation="1" class="flex" style="background-color:lightblue">
        I should fill the remaining height of the screen. xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    </paper-material>
  </div>

  <div class="flex-3">
        <paper-material elevation="1" style="background-color:lightpink">
          I should be to the right. My height should be based on my content.
        </paper-material>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your code, the very top level `div` doesn't wrap the second `paper-material` inside and that's why the latter never gets positioned on the right side.

To have the first `paper-material` fill the rest of the page, I had to put it inside another `vertical layout` `div` and make itself `flex`. On the other hand, for the second `paper-material` to only take the height based on its own content, I just needed to wrap it inside a `div` and assign the `flex-3` to this new `div` instead.

That's all! Please check out this updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lk5uNMGQUs9lKkSwktQw?p=preview) and it should show the output like below.

[image: demo]

Comment: plunker preview no longer seems to work, why reference non-existing http://element-party.xyz/all-elements.html>?

Comment: reference http://kasperpeulen.github.io/PolymerElements/all.html as an alternative to element-party.xyz

Comment: As a polymer newbie and wannabee, I wonder why Polymer users apparently needlessly complicate things? The plunkr example wraps the output into a <app-view> element which in turn uses an <view-1> element which uses a template which uses javascript etc. How does that help clarifying how to create a working layout?  Shouldn't webcomponents and other custom elements be created only when re-used (which clearly is not the case in this example)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Jsbin link that take advantage of layout and flex positioning in Polymer to achieve what you want , I hope it can help you.[Layout Exemple](http://plnkr.co/edit/VG3AS92M6JtKKevlPEOv?p=preview)
Polymer team created a set of layout examples and layout elements and you can certainly find useful , [Polymer Layout Examples](https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout-templates).

here is How your app-view element will look like

```html
<dom-module id="app-view">

  <style is="custom-style">
    :host {
      display: flex;
      @apply(--layout-vertical);
      --paper-button-ink-color: green;
    }
    
    paper-button {
      background-color: #FF5252;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .main {
      width: 100%;
      border: 1px solid yellow;
      @apply(--layout-horizontal);
    }
    
    .right {
      border: 1px solid black;
      @apply(--layout-vertical);
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      padding: 5px;
      @apply(--layout-flex-3);
    }
    
    .contentA {
      border: 1px solid green;
      height: 20%;
      @apply(--layout-vertical);
      @apply(--layout-center-center);
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    .contentB {
      height: 100%;
    
      @apply(--layout-vertical);
      @apply(--layout-flex-1);
      @apply(--layout-center-center);
      border: 1px solid orange;
    }
    
    .contentC {
      height: 350px;
      @apply(--layout-vertical);
      @apply(--layout-flex);
      @apply(--layout-center-center) border: 1px solid gray;
    }
  </style>
  <template>

    <paper-header-panel flex>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <div class="spacer title">My App</div>
      </paper-toolbar>


      <div class="main">

        <div class="right">
          <div class="contentA"> Content A
            <paper-button on-click="toggleView">toggle view</paper-button>
          </div>
          <div class="contentB">
            Content B
            <neon-animated-pages selected="{{selectedPageIndex}}" entry-animation="fade-in-animation" exit-animation="fade-out-animation">
              <view-1></view-1>
              <view-2></view-2>
            </neon-animated-pages>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="contentC"> Content c</div>

      </div>
    </paper-header-panel>

  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "app-view",
      properties: {
        selectedPageIndex: Number
      },
      ready: function() {
        this.selectedPageIndex = 0;
      },
      toggleView: function() {
       if(this.selectedPageIndex == 1)
        this.selectedPageIndex = 0;
        else
         this.selectedPageIndex = 1;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for sharing. However, when I open the Plunkr, the header does not stay fixed and the "View 2" content goes beyond the bottom of the frame. I'm trying to make it so that the content fills the remaining part of the screen. Then, the contents of that filled area scoll.